# IloNumArray Declaration in C++ cplex

Tags: c++, cplex

In ILOG Cplex C++, is there a way to set the value of an "IloNumArray" to negative infinity?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

An array of length len, with -inf as lower bound, and something else as upper bound.

```
IloRangeArray(env,len,-IloInfinity,ub);
```